# NAudio stream to Windows Mediaplayer

Tags: c#, media-player, naudio

I have Windows MediaPlayer embed on a page. I have a audio file(WAV) in MemoryStream I got from a byte[] array. I need to use NAudio to play that file in memory. how can I point the src of the MediaPlayer to the in memory file?

Comment: why not let NAudio play it itself?

Comment: Requirements! (The bane and reason for of my life!)

Comment: the only plugin I can use on the page is Widows MediaPlayer. but I could scripts a foo player and user JS to control it. I just cant have the wav outside of memory.

Comment: is this a webpage? How were you planning to use NAudio inside a webpage? Or is NAudio on your web server?

Comment: on the server.  I just need to hold the file in memory and point a player at it. the file can not be written to the server. I have it as a byte[] in object held on the server. I need to server my player that byte[] and have it play the audio. I was hoping I could have NAudio help me with that if not I may need to find a deferent way to do it.

Comment: Your problem is a bit outside the scope of NAudio. Your web server needs to return streaming audio, and WAV is not really the best option for that.